# VBA xlookup issue

Tags: excel, vba, lookup

I am trying to do a lookup on a column in which the values rise and fall.  for example, they may go like this: 4,5,6,4,3,2,1,4,6,8,9,11,9,8....  So, if I was looking for a "3" value in the series, i want to know the 1st time in the series, 3 (or the next smaller number) will reappear.  In the example, the 1st time would be item(5) in the list

I have been working with xlookup, vlookup, index/match, and none of them see capable of giving the correct result.  I either get an error message, or I get the wrong value returned.
Here are a few of the codes i have tried, unsuccessfully:

```
'nextDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match _
              (todayAspect, searchRng, -1)
             
 'nextDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup _
              (todayAspect, searchRng, returnRng, , -1))
             
 nextDate = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("A4:A5908"), _
              WorksheetFunction.Match(todayAspect, Range("u4:u5908"), -1))
```

Anyone have any insight as to my mistake?  Thanks in advance...

Comment: For example - `=MATCH(TRUE,$A$1:$A$10<=3,0)`

Comment: That was a good idea, but the code is giving me a 'Type mismatch" error.  The vba code i tried was:   nextDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match _
              (True, Range("u4:u5908") >= Range("u3").Value, 0)

Comment: I suspect my problem is that the lookup functions all expect the search range to be sorted low to high, and my data is not.  If so, is there a solution that does not include sorting the data on each iteration of the code?  Another non-attractive solution is to give up on the lookup functions and have a for loop the loops thru the range until it finds a value that meets the criteria.  But that would cause the code to run for hours...

Comment: `ws.Evaluate("MATCH(TRUE, U4:U5908<=" & todayAspect & ",0)")` should return the index of the first match, or an error if no match.  You can use that to index into ColA.  `ws` is the worksheet where your data is.

Comment: That worked.  I really appreciate your thoughtful insight.  I can see I need to investigate the evaluate function.  I have never utilized it until now.  Thanks again.

Comment: Evaluate is useful is you have a formula which isn't easily translatable to VBA.   Be aware there are two version: `Application.Evaluate` defaults to the context of whatever happens to be the active sheet, whereas `Worksheet.Evaluate` uses a specific worksheet.  I would avoid the first one and always use the second.

Comment: Can I impose to ask 1 more question? In the example, 'U4:U5908' works, but in my code I need to loop through hundreds of columns, so the range needs to be in the form of " cells(4,20),cells(5908,loopCounter) ".  Any thoughts on how to accomplish that?  I apologize if I'm asking too much.

Comment: If `rng` is the range you want to check: `ws.Evaluate("MATCH(TRUE, " & rng.Address(False, False) & "<=" & todayAspect & ",0)")`  If that's not clear then  you could add more relevant code above and I can re-phrase it to fit your code...

Comment: I'll work with that.  You have been very helpful.  I am grateful.